# Finding the TotalSpent for each Customer in Scala

Tags: scala

I am working on a simple requirement to find out the totalSpent by each Customer . If a Customer did not spend anything then I need to display TotalSpent Amount as 0 to him

**custs.txt :**

```
 100,Surender
 101,Raja
 102,Vijay
```

**txns.txt :**

```
 100,2015-01-29,20
 100,2015-01-30,18
 101,2015-01-14,30
 101,2015-01-17,20
```

Scala Code :

```
 import scala.io.Source

 case class Txns(custId: Int, txn_dateString: String,  spentAmount: Int)
 object totalamounteachcustomer {


  def main (args: Array[String])={


 val myCusts=Source.fromFile("C:\\inputfiles\\custs.txt").getLines().toList;

 val custsTxns=Source.fromFile("C:\\inputfiles\\txns.txt").getLines().toList;

val TxnsGrped =custsTxns.map { x => {
                                     val Array(custId,txn_dateString,spentAmount) = x.split(",")
                                     Txns(custId.toInt,txn_dateString,spentAmount.toInt)

                                     }
                              }.groupBy { txn => txn.custId }

        for(i <- myCusts)
        {
         val customer= i.split(",")(0).toInt
         val values =TxnsGrped.get(customer)

         val TotalSpentAmpunt = values match {

           case Some( a:List[Txns]) => a.map { x => x.spentAmount }.sum
           case None => 0

                                              }

         println(customer+" "+TotalSpentAmpunt)
        }
 }

 }
```

The above code works..

Output :

```
 100 38
 101 50
 102 0
```

Do we have simple Join Keywords in scala? If we need to get values based on common key between two files then can't we use something like Join(inner join, left join) in scala?

Here, I am using scala collection Map and iterate it over against each Customer.

Can we achieve this same requirement with simple  lines of scala code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implementing join of maps is a piece of cake in Scala:

```
def join[K, A, B](a: Map[K, A], b: Map[K, B]): Map[K, (A,B)] =
    for((k,va) <- a; vb <- b.get(k)) yield k -> (va, vb)
```

Use example:

```
val customers = Map(
 100 -> "Surender",
 101 -> "Raja",
 102 -> "Vijay"
)

val purchases = Seq(
 (100,"2015-01-29",20),
 (100,"2015-01-30",18),
 (101,"2015-01-14",30),
 (101,"2015-01-17",20)
) groupBy(_._1)

join(customers, purchases) mapValues { case (_, l) => l.map(_._3).sum }
```

You can make of `join` an infix operation by wrapping it in an implicit class:

```
implicit class C[K, A](a: Map[K, A]) {

    def join[B](b: Map[K, B]): Map[K, (A,B)] =
        for((k,va) <- a; vb <- b.get(k)) yield k -> (va, vb)

}

customers join purchases
```

Note that this join implementation (inner join) is easily modificable to behave as a left-join:

```
implicit class C[K, A](a: Map[K, A]) {

    def join[B](b: Map[K, B]): Map[K, (A,B)] =
        for((k,va) <- a; vb <- b.get(k)) yield k -> (va, vb)

    def leftJoin[B](b: Map[K, B], default: B): Map[K, (A,B)] =
        for((k,va) <- a; vb = b.getOrElse(k, default)) yield k -> (va, vb)

}
```

And then use it with you data to get exactly the result you are looking for:

```
customers leftJoin(purchases, Seq()) mapValues {
    case (_, l) => l.map(_._3).sum
}

> res: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(100 -> 38, 101 -> 50, 102 -> 0)
```

Comment: def join[K, A, B](a: Map[K, A], b: Map[K, B]): Map[K, (A,B)] =
      for((k,va) <- a; vb <- b.get(k)) yield k -> (va, vb)  . Here , What is the use of square brackets join[K, A, B]? . also this method returns Map . the Type for value  of returning Map is Tuple?

Comment: @SurenderRaja What is inside the square brackets is the type parameters of the method which are there in order to make it work with maps having any type of key and value.

Comment: @SurenderRaja The result is a tuple containing the joined value. Which type could you use to store two instances of different types? A tuple. E.g: You have a map from integer to string and another from integer to double. If you join them, the only reasonable result type for the resulting map values is (String, Double)

Comment: Lets say if I want to have a return as Map[K,C] here C is a String                      def join[K,A,B,C](custs:Map[K,A],txns:Map[K,B]) :Map[K, C]=
  {
    
   for((k,va) <- custs; vb <- txns.get(k)) yield k -> va.toString()+" " +vb.toString()
    
  }   .. While running this code I get error as type mismatch found .  ◾type mismatch; found : scala.collection.mutable.Iterable[String] required: scala.collection.mutable.Map[K,C]

Comment: @SurenderRaja If you want to add a parametric type for the result `C`, then you'll need to provide a function to build a value of that type from a value of type `A` and a value of type `B`:

`def join[K, A, B, C](a: Map[K, A], b: Map[K, B], combiner: (A, B) => C: Map[K, (A,B)] =
    for((k,va) <- a; vb <- b.get(k)) yield k -> combiner(va,vb)`

But I see it overkill since you can apply a combiner to the Map[K, (A,B)] original result using `mapValues`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121325/discussion-between-surender-raja-and-pablo-francisco-perez-hidalgo).

Comment: I Understood your answer, Thanks for your help !

Answer (score -1):

Let's look at basics. Inner and Outer Joins are part of SQL for databases. If you have a SQL database, you can use Scala to query it and you can execute join operations. If you have your data in as collection of csv files, then you need an engine that turns it into an SQL supporting RDBMS, and can then do the joins.

In other words, in Scala, as in Java, C#, or any other language, database is an implementation detail that one works out during development. No other language can directly join files with out first using some kind of a wrapper AFAIK.

If I had to do what you are showing here, I would import my csv files to a SQL database, from SQLite to Oracle, SQL server, Mysql, take-your-pick, and then query that database, worst case scenario through JDBC.

Comment: The join operation - as a concept - exits outside SQL. You can implement join operations for key-value data structures in any language.

Once the OP loads its data into that kind of data structure from the TXT files, using an external service just to perform a join seems a little overkill.

Comment: This isn't really a useful answer.  As @PabloFranciscoPérezHidalgo points out, `join` is not unique to SQL and can easily be done in scala, as the other answer points out.

Comment: Sure. feel free to downvote anything with which you don't agree personally. however, Join is, in fact a relation database concept. the fact that you can simulate it by traversing two lists is universal and is not specific to Scala at all. As I said in my answer, you need to implement a wrapper, which is exactly what the other answer has done. I can do that in any language. with some practice, I am sure you would too.